I am doing upgrade for my ext js application from 4.2 to 7.7. Way of creating charts is not working
During the upgrade from Ext js 4.2 to 7.7, unable to create chart and it is saying Ext.chart.Chart is not found. Also tried with Ext.chart.CartesianChart but again getting same error .
https://9791859.app.netsuite.com/app/center/Ext/chart/CartesianChart.js?_dc=1717301742842.404 (Not Found)
While searching for solution , found like we have to add a chart package by adding requires:[Ext.chart.*]. But I am confused on where to add this.
I am creating a chart on a panel and using classic toolkit.
Could someone please help me on this?

did you include it in app.json?

I don't have app.json in my application
